# как добавить Google карту с указанием нужного места

Tags: карты

Я когда то делал это, но очень давно, поэтому я не помню как это сделать. Google нормально не можеть мне предоставить нужную мне информацию, поэтому спрашиваю здесь. Как сделать, чтобы на сайте была карта с указаным местом пункта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. На сайте Google Maps выбираете локацию.
2. Выбираете "Поделиться"
3. Встраивание карт
4. Копировать HTML

`PROFIT`